# Maven project compile error, trying to implement secrets manager

Tags: java, scala

I am working on implementing secrets manager to etl pipeline. And for this I am using HikariDataSource but it throws following error:
In order to debug my code, I commented every bit of line except below and I am still getting `error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'HikariDataSourceFactory.class'` How can I get details of what is missing?

My code:

```
import com.miemo.commonlib.rdb.HikariDataSourceFactory

object RdbmsToSflake extends App with Logging {
       val dataSourceFactory = new HikariDataSourceFactory {}
}
```

output for mvn compile:

```
[INFO] Building s3-to-dwh 0.1                                   [3/4]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ s3-to-dwh ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ s3-to-dwh ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (default) @ s3-to-dwh ---
[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.11.7
[WARNING]  com.miemo:s3-to-dwh:0.1 requires scala version: 2.11.7
[WARNING]  org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-runtime_2.11:1.1.1 requires scala version: 2.11.7
[WARNING]  org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-plugin_2.11:1.1.1 requires scala version: 2.11.7
[WARNING]  org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:2.2.4 requires scala version: 2.11.2
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!
[INFO] /Users/myusername/Documents/my-git-repo/my-repo/s3-to-dwh/src/main/scala:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/myusername/Documents/my-git-repo/my-repo/s3-to-dwh/target/classes at 1664178114387
[ERROR] error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'HikariDataSourceFactory.class'.
[INFO] Could not access term zaxxer in package com,
[INFO] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
[INFO] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
[INFO] A full rebuild may help if 'HikariDataSourceFactory.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.
[ERROR] one error found
```

After debugging pom.xml, I got to find out that below plugin is messing somehow.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                    <goal>testCompile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <sourceDir>src/main/scala</sourceDir>
            <args>
                <arg>-Xlint:_</arg>
                <arg>-language:postfixOps</arg>
            </args>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Final Edit: @Tobias's answer helped me with this.

Comment: show us your pom/dependencies! (sounds like something missing/messed up). I would also not ignore these scala-plugin-warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a missing dependecy `zaxxer in package com` announced in the maven log which you posted.

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer
- https://www.baeldung.com/hikaricp

Can you add this to your maven pom and do a clean build?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is there any rule which version to use, or anything will work?

Comment: The version depends sometimes on other dependencies which might require a different version (older as example) because the code of the dependency depends on some obsolete api of a dependency which got removed in a newer version. I think that is an explanation for which version we have to use in a project. That can be solved by increasing the other dependency to a newer version then…